# Is there an API call for searching datastreams?

Tags: xively, cosm

In the Xively API, [I found a way to search for *feeds*](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/quick_reference/search_feeds/), but what I really wanted is a way to search within datastreams. For example, I want the most recent five datapoints that == 1. I looked at the "[historical data](https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/quick_reference/historical_data/)" API and could not find such functionality. Do I have to write the search algorithm manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not provided by Xively APIv2, you will indeed need to check the values manually.